# Drupal 7 views show nodes filtered by user profile field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7 views show nodes filtered by user profile field

In Drupal 7,
create taxonomy vocabulary "Interests".
It has terms sports, arts, computer...

admin/structure/profiles
create main profile.
It has field with term reference to "Interests" taxonomy.

The node is related to "Interests" terms also.

Want to create a view to only display the nodes that users are interested.
For example, if a user profile has only terms sport and computer, then only nodes related 
with "Interests" sport or computer show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new View showing Users, rather than Content.
- Add a contextual filter for `User: Uid` with the default value `User ID from logged in user`.
- Add `Fields: Interests` as a relationship.
- Add `Taxonomy term: Content using Interests` as a relationship.
- Replace the User fields displayed with Content fields.